# How would I lift state in this small randomizer so that I can have it as a component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using this small app to enter names and then randomly picking names from the array when it is fully entered. From what I can understand, I should lift the state from the inputs in to the parent class component. Further than that, can I abstract the JSX into a separate file and import it after the state has been moved to the parent?

I am very new to this so I am confused at how to do this in a way that makes sure everything still works. Essentially, I would want to just be able to have a component called in the main instance and give props that would share the state with the component and then be able to pass the updated state from the component to the parent. Is that possible? I am very confused and would love any help and solutions.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        value: '',
        name: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleEnter =  this.handleEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleRandomize = this.handleRandomize.bind(this);
}



handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value    
  }) 
 }

 handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({
    value: '',
    name: this.state.name.concat(this.state.value)    
  })
  console.log(this.state.name);
 }

 handleEnter(e) {
 if (e.key === 'Enter') {
   this.handleSubmit();
 }
 }

 handleRandomize() {
 let randVal = this.state.name;

 let speaker = randVal[Math.floor(Math.random() * randVal.length)];

 console.log(speaker);
 }

render(){

return (
<div>
  <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.handleEnter}/>
  <br></br>
  <button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}>Submit Name</button>
  <button onClick = {this.handleRandomize}>Randomize!</button>

<ul>{this.state.name.map((names) => <li key={names.toString()}>{names}</li>)}</ul>
</div>
  ) 
 }
};
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. In general you can move functionality to wherever you want; to "pass state back" to a parent send a callback as a prop to that component. For example your text input could be a separate component but would get its value and onchange/keypress functions as props.

Comment: This is what I am confused about. You nailed what I am trying to do, but I cannot envision what it looks like. In this case, I would have the onkeypress/onchange and value in the parent component and then pass those as props to the child? Then when I update the child it updates the parent state and stores the values in the array?

What would passing these as props look like? An example snippet would help me visualize it more.

Comment: `<SomeInputComponent value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />` etc. Then the input component would wrap the text input. Not super-helpful in this case, but as the input stuff gets more complex (labels, additional DOM elements, etc) it starts to make sense.

Comment: Then what does it look like inside of the file for the component itself? Do I need to bind another handler in the SomeInputComponent file to actually call the onChange handler e.g. 

`handleChange(e) {
this.props.onChange(e.target.value)
}
`
And then attach that to the text input inside the child component?

Comment: Just call the function you passed in.

Comment: What might that look like? I am still learning about passing functions into components via the docs and some Udemy courses so a short example would help me tons, even if it is unrelated to my code.

Comment: `<... onChange={this.props.onChange} ... />` Where the function comes from doesn't matter--it's just a reference to a function.

Comment: Thanks so much, Dave! I'll give this a go. You've been a great help.